# How can i make tkinter work with time.sleep

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to make a program that every 24 hours updates text with tkinter.
The window opens without time.sleep(), but not with it active. I also tried after() but im unsure if i used it even correctly (decently new to coding).

```
from tkinter import *
import time


obj = Tk()
obj.title("Hey")
obj.geometry("300x300")
wintext = Text(obj)
wintext.insert(INSERT, "I ")
time.sleep(86400)
wintext.insert(INSERT, "LIKE ")
time.sleep(86400)
wintext.insert(INSERT, "CUTE ")
time.sleep(86400)
wintext.insert(END, "CATS :)")
wintext.pack()
obj.mainloop()


from tkinter import *
import time


obj = Tk()
obj.title("Hey")
obj.geometry("300x300")
wintext = Text(obj)
wintext.insert(INSERT, "I ")
wintext.after(3, "LIKE ")
#wintext.insert(INSERT, "CUTE ")
#wintext.insert(END, "CATS :)")
wintext.pack()
obj.mainloop()
```

but get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/things/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    wintext.after(3, "LIKE ")
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 820, in after
    callit.__name__ = func.__name__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: ```wintext.after(3000, lambda: wintext.insert(INSERT, "LIKE "))```.```time.sleep``` messes with the ```mainloop```. Also, ```after()```'s first argument takes number in **milliseconds**. You should multiply that with a thousand to convert it to seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

# import time

obj = Tk()
obj.title("Hey")
obj.geometry("300x300")
wintext = Text(obj)
wintext.insert(INSERT, "I ")

# wintext.after(3, "LIKE ")
wintext.after(3000, lambda: wintext.insert(INSERT, "LIKE "))  # 3 s

# wintext.insert(INSERT, "CUTE ")
# wintext.insert(END, "CATS :)")

wintext.pack()
obj.mainloop()
```

This seems to work: `after` expects a function.